# Why GMail is not accepting credentials?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, httpwebrequest, credentials

I am using following code to display gmail login page

```
    WebRequest myRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://www.gmail.com");
    WebResponse myResponse = myRequest.GetResponse();
    Stream sr = myResponse.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader sre = new StreamReader(sr);
    string s = sre.ReadToEnd();
    Response.Write(s);
    myResponse.Close();
```

But when I fill Username and Password and click Sign In, it does not log me in and remain on the same page.

Basically I want to store my different login details (GMail, Yahoo, Facebook etc.) in my ASP.NET application and when I click GMail link it should fill Username and Password so that when I click Sign In it should login and show Inbox.

Comment: I'd be wary of any site that wanted to "store" my credentials for Google, Facebook, or any other site.  An accepted practice is to use OAuth.  See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2

Comment: @JonathanS. "wary" is an understatement.

Comment: @Jonathan S. : Thanks for reply. I will read it. It is not a website it is a private application for personal use only.

Comment: @user1390378 in that case, consider using a browser plug-in to manage your credentials. I use LastPass but there are several good ones out there.

Comment: @Jonathan S.: Yes this is an option, but I want browser independent solution. Like web application which can be access by any browser.